# wha does file descriptor 3 and `wheel `mean in /dev/fd

Tags: bash, macos

when I check `/dev/fd`

```
$ ls -l /dev/fd | sed "s/$USER/mememe/g"
total 0
crw--w---- 1 mememe tty   16, 1 Nov 13 12:52 0
prw-rw---- 0 mememe staff     0 Nov 13 12:52 1
crw--w---- 1 mememe tty   16, 1 Nov 13 12:52 2
dr--r--r-- 1 root   wheel     0 Nov 13 07:32 3
```

what does fd `3` and the wheel mean?

Comment: It's the file descriptor number and the owner group name of the open dir. Is anything unclear about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> Modern Unix systems generally use user groups as a security protocol
>   to control access privileges. The **wheel** group is a special user group
>   used on some Unix systems to control access to the su or sudo command,
>   which allows a user to masquerade as another user (usually the super
>   user)